# Construct generic Struct from a Trait function in Rust

Tags: generics, design-patterns, rust, traits, higher-kinded-types

I want to write a trait that allows me to construct new structs of the implementing type, but with different type parameters. For example, say I hav some struct

```rust
struct Generic<T> {
    t: T,
}
```

and I want a trait `Constructable` that lets me call `Generic::new_from_q::<Q>(q as Q)`, i.e. my trait would look like this (in pseudo-rust):

```rust
trait Constructable {
    fn new_from_q<Q>(q: Q) -> Self<Q>; // Self<Q> would be e.g. Generic<Q>
}

impl<T> Constructable for Generic<T> {
    type T = T;
    fn new_from_q<Q>(q: Q) -> Generic<Q> {
        Generic { t: q }
    }
}
```

Of course this makes no sense since the trait cannot guarantee that `Self` will be able to take the type parameter `Q`. The closest I have come to implementing the desired constructor behaviour is this:

```rust
trait Constructable {
    type T;
    fn new_from_q<Q>(q: Q) -> impl Constructable<T = Q>; // currently invalid
}
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa81dd1ab4e9092f179d4d982aa1ddbd)) which is currently not possible due to the limitations of the `impl Trait` syntax (see [#34511](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34511)), which is (I think)

- not allowed in traits
- not able to take values for associated types

So, how do I work around these limitations? Is there some common programming pattern to allow me to do this (I would like to avoid dynamic trait objects)?

Comment: I don't actually get the real purpose of doing this but are you looking a solution like this : [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2ef22ce0777f9b8107a71af9969ae333)?

Comment: My concrete use case is that I have a bunch of structs (representing numerical integrators and implementing an `Integrator` trait) storing a closure (the function being integrated), and want to be able to create new instances of those structs but storing a different closure (create a new integrator of the same algorithm type, but over a new equation). I don't think your solution would work here.

Comment: This sounds like a custom [`Into`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e8aa5e77d3f2abbd11c9b7b3fef3b56f) trait. Take a look at the [std `Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html).